# Instaparse: Is negation supported?

Tags: instaparse

The `-` operator is supposed to support negation, but I can't get it to work:

```
raw-type = "DINT" | "REAL" | "SINT" | "BIT"
custom-type = - raw-type
```

Every time I try I get the error: `RuntimeException - occurs on the right-hand side of your grammar, but not on the left  instaparse.cfg/check-grammar (cfg.clj:252)`. It doesn't seem to matter where I put the `-`.

So how to get past this error? Or is there another way of doing the `custom-type` above?

Answer (score 1):

`!` is negation.  Use `!` rather than `-`.